# Angularjs: Pass parameter from controller to factory

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have following code in service

```
define(['./module'], function(services) {
'use strict';
services.factory('user_resources', ['$resource', '$location', function($resource, $location) {
       return $resource("", {},
                {
                    'testService':{method:"GET",url:'http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?data={method:method_name,params:{param1:value,param2:value,}}',isArray:true}
                });
 }]);
});
```

from controller i am calling this factory method how to pass parameters to this testService from controller?

following is code in controller to call this factory

```
user_resources.testService().$promise.then(function(data) {
  console.log("****************************");        
  console.log(data);
  $scope.mylist=data;     
});
```

Comment: what parameter you want to pass?

Comment: want to pass this portion params:{param1:value,param2:value} as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not how `$resource` works.

```
$resource("http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php", 
            {'testService':{method:"GET",url:'http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php',isArray:true}})
```

Then you call it with:

```
var theObjToSend = {
                    method:method_name,
                    params:
                         {
                            param1:value,
                            param2:value
                         }
                   };
new user_resources({data: theObjToSend}).testService();
```

or

```
user_resources.testService({data: theObjToSend});
```

Its going to serialize the object so it might look weird.  Any reason why you dont use query parameters?
e.g.

```
?method=method_name&params={param1:value,param2:value}
```

Comment: if i open 'testService':{method:"GET",url:'http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php?data={',isArray:true} and user_resources.testService({data: theObjToSend}).$promise.then(function(data){
                console.log("####################");
                console.log(data);
            }); then data is not available

Comment: I dont understand your comment @PriyaBhatt

Comment: i am using user_resources.testService({data: theObjToSend}).$promise.then(function(data){ console.log("####################"); console.log(data); }); to get data from url but it is not available

Answer (score 1):

You should really check this vid: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-resource-for-data-models

```
return $resource("http://11.11.11.11/url/index.php");
```